# Changing default (outgoing) codec to OPUS in Freeswitch

Tags: codec, pjsip, freeswitch, opus

I am new to Freeswitch.
I want to change the default codec to OPUS. I made changes to vars.xml,dingaling.xml as per 
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Codecs+and+Media. I have loaded the mod_opus module as well.

But still I am receving the RTP in PCMA/PCMU following the link . When I do eval  $${global_codec_prefs} I get OPUS,PCMA,PCMU,VP8. Please let me know what am I missing.

Also, I am using PJSIP as one of the SIP clients. Do I need to make any changes in PJSIP too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running latest FreeSWITCH (1.6.9) you need to add media_mix_inbound_outbound_codecs=true to vars.xml.